# Get the number of data entries in another file?

Tags: c++, arrays, external

I need to know if you can easily get the number of data entries in another file and save that number in the original file. Need a program that will process the other file no matter how many entries are in it. Hope that makes any sense.

Comment: Does my answer address your problem? If not let me know. If so please mark it as an answer (click on the "correct mark" beside the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very poorly worded but I think you are looking for [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). This function can parse an input file based on the newline character (default behaviour) or based on a user provided delimiter:

```
int entryCount = 0;
std::string currentLine;
std::ifstream inFile( "in.txt" );
std::ofstream outFile;
if (inFile)  // short for inFile.good())
{
    while (std::getline( inFile, currentLine))
    {
        ++entryCount;
        // Do your processing
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.open( "out.txt" );
    outFile << "End of file. " << entryCount << " entries read." << std::endl;
    outFile.close();
}
else
    std::cout << "oops... error opening inFile" << std::endl;
```